# How do you get StoryTest to work?

Tags: tdd

Does StoryTest (http://storytestiq.solutionsiq.com/wiki/Main_Page) work?  Everything on the wiki is under construction.

If you have gotten it to work, can you share how you did it?

Answer (score 2):

While StoryTest appears to be a very cool approach to managing Selenium and FitNesse type tests, there has been no activity on that project in a year.  I would chalk it up to abandoned.

I would consider using Selenium with SpecFlow to achieve a similar result that could be run from your continuous integration server.

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/)

Steven Sanderson has an awesome article on his blog about using SpecFlow with WatiN, his technique should be in the neighborhood of what you are attempting to accomplish.
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/03/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with-specflow-and-aspnet-mvc/